# Can Jackson deserialize to a concrete subsclass using a boolean JSON property it didn't write?

Tags: java, json, jackson, polymorphism, deserialization

I'm using Jackson to deserialize a JSON file received from elsewhere - that is to say I have control over the deserialization, but not the serialization.

Let's say the JSON describes a flat list with a mixture of aquatic and land-based animals.

One of the animal JSON properties is the boolean `isAquatic`. In Java, `AquaticAnimal` and `LandAnimal` are separate classes, each subclasses of the abstract class `Animal`, which contains member data relevant to both subtypes of animal. Animal has no other subclasses, and never will have. Aquatic animals have properties like gills that make no sense to a `LandAnimal` (and thus a `LandAnimal` will never have such a property in the JSON, and the subclass provides associated behaviour). Likewise, the same is true in inverse for land animals, which may have paws, lungs etc. (It's not a perfect example, but it serves its purpose)

**When deserializing, I want to use the value of `isAquatic` to decide which subclass to use** when I do the following:

```java
Animal animal = mapper.readValue( ... , Animal.class);
```

All examples of dealing with polymorphism have involved writing extra data into the JSON when serializing it with Jackson, but I'm only reading in the data, so I can't do this easily. However, I can determine the correct class from information already in the JSON, so I'd like to do that.

I don't fully understand the Jackson tags, but based on other examples, I'd like to be able to do something like this:

```java
@JsonSubTypes({
    @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = LandAnimal.class, isAquatic = false),

    @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = AquaticAnimal.class, isAquatic = true) }
)
public abstract class Animal {
    ...
```

I'm sure this isn't how that annotation is meant to be used, but hopefully it explains what I'm trying to do.

Can anyone tell me whether Jackson can do this, and if so, how?

Comment: This smells like a job for a custom deserialiser

Comment: @JonK: Possibly. If I give a `new ObjectMapper()` the correct subclass to deserialize to, it works just fine for both subclasses (constructors and their parameters have the appropriate annotations). The only problem is that Jackson can't work out which one to construct. As there are examples of Jackson doing that using only annotations and information in the JSON, I wondered if that solution can be fitted to my situation, which seems cleaner than  writing a custom deserializer.

Comment: @M_M you are correct, it is possible for Jackson to evaluate a field value to determine what class to create from a json object. Please see the answer below

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible with some nice handy dandy notation work:

```
@JsonTypeInfo(  
    use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME,  
    include = JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY,  
    property = "isAquatic")
@JsonSubTypes({
    @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = LandAnimal.class, name = "false"),
    @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = AquaticAnimal.class, name = "true") 
})
public abstract class Animal {
    private String isAquatic;
    ...
```

this will take you property `isAquatic` and mape it to the json type field `name` and then return the proper class depending on what that name is;

NOTE: I've only done this approach with fields that are Strings thus the reason why i made `isAquatic` a String, you might be able to try other approaches to see if it works with booleans.

Comment: Good news: This works, also when the property (field) is a `boolean` instead of a `String`: the quotes don't cause any problems. The only problem I had was that my Java base class had methods named `void setAsAquatic(boolean)` and `boolean isAquatic()`, which Jackson interpreted as corresponding to properties `asAquatic` and `aquatic` respectively. The JSON input contained `"isAquatic":true`, so I just needed to annotate my getter and setter with `@JsonProperty("isAquatic")`. Accepting this answer as the solution works, and +1 for use of the phrase "handy dandy". :-)